# Why is only one wget command working in my crontab?

Tags: cron, wget

I wish to fetch content from a PHP script on my server two times a day, altering a query variable `lang` to set what language we want, and save this content in two language specific files. This is my crontab:

```
*/15 * * * * ~root/apache.sh > /var/log/checkapache.log
10 0 * * * wget -O /path/to/file-sv.sql "http://mydomain.com/path/?lang=sv"
11 0 * * * wget -O /path/to/file-en.sql "http://mydomain.com/path/?lang=en"
```

The problem is that only the first wget command line is being executed (or to be precise: the only file that is being written is `/path/to/file-sv.sql`). If I switch the second and the third row, `/path/to/file-en.sql` gets written instead. The first line always runs as expected, no matter where it is.

I then tried using `lynx -dump "http://mydomain.com/path/?lang=xx" > /path/to/file-xx.sql` to no avail; still only the first lynx line executed successfully. **Even mixing wget and lynx did not change this!**

Getting kinda desperate! Am I missing something? There are thousands of articles on crontab (combined with) wget or lynx, but all seems to cover basic setups and syntax. Does anyone got a clue of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alexander

Comment: Are you sure that whenever you access http://mydomain.com/path/?lang=en something is returned ? have you tried this from a command line to see what happens (wget -O - http://mydomain.com/path/?lang=en) ?

Comment: I would try erasing and recreating the carriage return between 2 and 3.

Comment: Best practice is to specify the full path to the executables in crontab.  Like: "/usr/bin/wget".  I don't think this would help in your case, since one of the crons works.

Comment: What is displayed in cron's log when this happens?

Comment: @Torian: Works like a charm.

Comment: @Antonius Bloch: I'm sorry, what is the carriage return, and how is this done?

Comment: @afEkenholm: What does the http://mydomain.com server have to say about the second request ? Does it see it and what does it do with it ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try adding newline at the end of your crontab.

Comment: You're a godsend! That did it! I'd vote you up if I had the reputation. :)

Comment: @gelraen But... why?

Answer (score 3):

I just spent some time trying the above answers (adding newlines, deleting newlines, etc.) on a system running **cronie**. Finally found there is a bug in **cronie 1.5.3** that *only executes the first cron job for each user*. It's fixed in **1.5.4**

https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/issues/30

Hope this saves someone some time...

Answer (score 2):

There's something about the text that's wrong. Edit your crontab in vim then show invisible characters.

```
:set invlist
```

You should be able to see and then correct it.

Comment: Wrong how? How do I edit it in Vim? I tried rewriting the whole file in the case that copy-pasting would cause problems.

Comment: @afEkenholm: how do you edit it now?

Comment: @bahamat: `# crontab -e`

Comment: @afEkenholm: do this: `EDITOR=vim crontab -e`

Comment: @bahamat: Everything looks just fine. Got a purple `$` at the end of each line?

Comment: @afEkenholm: Did you also type `:set invlist`?

Comment: @bahamat Sure did. That's when they appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try add redirect, to debug crontab(or read root mail):

```
11 0 * * * wget -O /path/to/file-en.sql "http://mydomain.com/path/?lang=en" > /tmp/crontab_ouptput 2> /tmp/crontab_error
```

Also run 'wget -O /path/to/file-en.sql "http://mydomain.com/path/?lang=en"' from console.

Also use 'crontab -e' for validation new crontab.

Also, try delete not working line and retype it from keyboard.

Backup corntab and run command:

```
crontab -l | crontab -
```

Comment: Adding `/tmp/crontab_ouptput 2> /tmp/crontab_error` only works for the first line. Running the command from the console works just fine. Rewrote the whole file with my bare hands, but nothing changed.

Comment: Backup crontab and try: crontab -l | crontab -

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, @alvosu, but a simple newline did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I also met with the same problem today. I found that it's caused by my server not using the same timezone I am at.

I fixed it by changing the timezone on the server (CentOS 7) with the command:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
timedatectl set-timezone <My timezone>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).