# /etc/crontab file not executed

Tags: centos, cron

I created a dummy entry in /etc/crontab, but it doesn't get executed according to cron log /var/log/cron:

```
Feb  7 08:20:01 localhost CROND[22781]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 08:30:01 localhost CROND[23132]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 08:40:01 localhost CROND[23137]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 08:50:01 localhost CROND[23147]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 09:00:01 localhost CROND[23922]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 09:01:01 localhost CROND[23977]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  7 09:01:01 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[23977]: starting 0anacron
Feb  7 09:01:01 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[23986]: finished 0anacron
Feb  7 09:10:01 localhost CROND[24264]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 09:20:01 localhost CROND[24295]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

/etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed

05 20 * * * root /data/CENTRAL_BACKUP/xxx.sh
```

the OS is centos

Comment: Your definition says to run it at 20:05; your logs do not cover that period. What time did you expect it to run at?

Comment: that's the end of the cron log, it means that nothing is logged to it since Feb 7th.

Comment: what are the permissions on the script? also did you manually edit /etc/crontab or did you use the crontab -e command?

Comment: Is your syslog daemon still running?

Comment: Very likely is crontab newline problem. Add empty line at the end.
http://serverfault.com/a/230407/41072

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that my system was messed up by selinux because I symlinked /var to another parition and selinux has permission issue with it.  I had to grant permission 777 to the symlink /var(not the data). and then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning the service off then back on again?  I came across a similar issue not too long ago configuring a backup script for our wiki server.  You have to restart the service to get it to load the new configuration, so if you haven't already, try that.

```
service cron restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```