# docker cron not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, containers

I am trying to build a docker image which would have a cron. A cron which will delete files from particular location of docker file system. Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER docker@ekito.fr

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Copy testfiles folder to docker container.
COPY ./testfiles /opt/

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN (crontab -l -u root; echo "* * * * * root rm -rf /opt/*") | crontab

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/bash"]
```

Everything is successful. my cron is also set in the container

```
roadrunner:test shailesh$ docker run -it crontest /bin/bash
root@ac31f5acc49f:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@ac31f5acc49f:/# crontab -l
* * * * * root rm -rf /opt/*
root@ac31f5acc49f:/# cd /opt/
root@ac31f5acc49f:/opt# ls  
file1  file10  file11  file12  file13  file14  file15  file16  file17  file18  file19  file2  file20  file21  file22  file23  file24  file25  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
```

However it is not running and deleting the files which are in `/opt/` folder. Can someone tell me what is wrong in the configuration.

Comment: Learn about [when to use ENTRYPOINT vs CMD](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try some thing like this,

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER docker@ekito.fr

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

create file crontab  and add an entry like this

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this isn't helping. It's not making a log entry in that location `/var/log/cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: Works great, but environment variables have not the same values than in interactive bash command line with same user

Comment: `failed running [/bin/sh -c "crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron"]: exit code: 127`

Comment: I think this answer used a wrong syntax for the job definition. When we use `crontab filename` to install cron jobs, the user field (`root` here) should not be put after `* * * * *`. See [Jenny's answer below](https://serverfault.com/a/976645/940850). The user field is needed only for `/etc/crontab` or files inside `/etc/cron.d/`. However, I don't know how to install jobs defined in these files. In ubuntu, `man cron` says `cron` also look for jobs in these files. However, in docker, they do not work. Don't know why

Comment: This answer was incredibly helpful. I needed to make 2 small adjustments: 1. Remove `root` from the line in the crontab file, and 2. Add an [empty line](https://serverfault.com/a/230407/474272) under that single line in the crontab to keep cron happy.

Answer (score 3):

Your crontab  syntax is wrong.

There are two places where you can place cron files:

- in the user's own crontab file, usually under `/var/spool/cron/USERNAME`. This is where things get placed automatically if you use the command `crontab`.
- in `/etc/cron.d`

If you place it in `/etc/cron.d`, the file must contain the name of the user you're running it under, since there's otherwise no connection between the file and the user. But if you use the `crontab` command, the cron specification will be placed in the crontab belonging to your user (or to the user you specify when invoking `crontab`), so you don't need to include the username.

So to fix this you can do either one of two things:

- You can remove the username from the string you're passing to the crontab command, so that it looks like this:

  ```
  RUN (crontab -l -u root; echo "* * * * * rm -rf /opt/*") | crontab
  ```
- You can place the crontab entry in a file under `/etc/cron.d` instead, like this:

  ```
  RUN (echo "* * * * * root rm -rf /opt/*" > /etc/cron.d/clearopt)
  ```

Comment: I found that your approach works. After executing `crontab`, `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` is generated, which contains job definitions (no `root` in job definition). However, I cannot get the second one work if I later run `cron -f` to start. I feel that in my ubuntu docker image, `cron -f` does not manage the files in `/etc/cron.d`. Did miss something to let `cron` read the files in `/etc/cron.d`?

Comment: EDIT for the previous comment: I should have typed "your **first approach** works".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue too. After lots of searching and testing I came up with this solution:
Be sure to install 'cron' from your Dockerfile. Then add these lines to your Dockerfile:

```
ADD cron_start.sh /docker-entrypoint.d
ADD healthcheck.sh /docker-entrypoint.d
```

The file cron_start.sh simply contains these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting cron"
service cron start
```

Then add this line to add your Dockerfile to create the crontab entry:

```
RUN (echo "* * * * * /docker-entrypoint.d/healthcheck.sh" | crontab -u root -)
```

Note, there is no need for an interim file if you tell crontab to get the data from stdin with the "-" flag.

Comment: Oh man, seriously !!? I had no idea that cron itself would be not running. Thank you very much for pointing it out. This fixed my issue.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue in the same context. My tip is to create a bash script to do whatever you want at the container's startup.
and then set the CMD in the Dockerfile to run it using JSON array syntax.

I have a file start.sh to do some stuff and I use `&` to run it in the background and then I run cron && apache2-foregroung to start the cron and the apache server.

This is the final command at the end of my Dockerfile:

```
CMD ./start.sh > web/startup.log & cron && apache2-foreground
```

Comment: But that runs at startup,not regularly.

Comment: @RalfFriedl I've got this running now and just edited my answer, look at this now and let me know if you still have some doubt

Comment: you need to start the cron process everytime you start the container, but we can have only one CMD command in Dockerfiles.